# Как задать абсолютный путь в reactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Есть код:

```
<div className={s.loginButtons}>
        <button>
          <NavLink to="/login">Login</NavLink>
        </button>
        <button className={s.signUpButton}>
          <NavLink to="https://social-network.samuraijs.com/signUp">
            Sign up
          </NavLink>
        </button>
      </div>
```

С относительным путём всё отлично, а абсолютный тоже отталкивается от корня сайта и получается

http://localhost:3000/viktor-gif-react#/https://social-network.samuraijs.com/signUp

вместо

https://social-network.samuraijs.com/signUp

Как исправить? Не судите строго, я новичок))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NavLink это ссылка для раутинга вашего сайта. Для перехода на другой сайт можно написать:

```
<a href="https://social-network.samuraijs.com/signUp">Sign up</a>
```

Для открытия окна на новой вкладвке:

```
<a
    href="https://social-network.samuraijs.com/signUp"
    target="_blank"
    rel="noopener noreferrer"
  >
    Sign up
</a>
```

Comment: Это первое что я сделал. Сейчас появилось время, посмотрел внимательней на код и обнаружил не то что ошибку, а опечатку. Вместо "href" написал "to". Ошибки не выдавало, просто не работало. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста, отлично что получилось! Отметь ответ как правильный если не сложно.